# How to get data from SNMP with python?

Tags: python, snmp, net-snmp, pysnmp, fdb

How to get value mac and vlan from fdb table uses python? 
In bash snmpwalk work fine:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c pub 192.168.0.100 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2
```

pysnmp:

```
import os, sys
import socket
import random
from struct import pack, unpack
from datetime import datetime as dt

from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
from pysnmp.proto.rfc1902 import Integer, IpAddress, OctetString

ip='192.168.0.100'
community='pub'
value=(1,3,6,1,2,1,17,7,1,2,2,1,2)

generator = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
comm_data = cmdgen.CommunityData('server', community, 1) # 1 means version SNMP v2c
transport = cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((ip, 161))

real_fun = getattr(generator, 'getCmd')
res = (errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds)\
    = real_fun(comm_data, transport, value)

if not errorIndication is None  or errorStatus is True:
       print "Error: %s %s %s %s" % res
else:
       print "%s" % varBinds
```

> output: [(ObjectName(1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2), NoSuchInstance(''))]

```python
import netsnmp

def getmac():
    oid = netsnmp.VarList(netsnmp.Varbind('.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2'))
    res = netsnmp.snmpgetbulk(oid, Version = 2, DestHost='192.168.0.100',
                           Community='pub')
    return res

print getmac()
```

> output: ('27', '27', '25', '27', '27', '27', '24', '27', '25', '18', '4',
>   '27', '25', '27', '27', '25', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27',
>   '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '23',
>   '25', '27', '27', '27', '25', '27', '25', '27', '27', '25', '27',
>   '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '25', '27', '27',
>   '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '25',
>   '25', '25', '7', '27', '27', '9', '25', '27', '20', '19', '27', '27',
>   '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27',
>   '27', '11', '25', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27',
>   '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '25', '27', '27', '27', '27',
>   '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '2', '27', '5', '27', '0', '27', '27',
>   '27', '27', '27')

Firs script(pysnmp) return NoSuchInstance. Second script(netsnmp) return list of ports but without mac and vlan. What wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the pysnmp example you are doing an SNMPGET (snmpget), not a GETNEXT (snmpwalk).  If you change,

```
real_fun = getattr(generator, 'getCmd')
```

to

```
real_fun = getattr(generator, 'nextCmd')
```

you will start to see useful results.

As for the discrepancy you saw in the results between `snmpwalk` and the python `net-snmp` bindings result: `snmpwalk` and `snmpbulkget` behave differently.  If you do an `snmpbulkget` from the command line with the same options as the `snmpwalk` you'll receive the same results as your python `net-snmp` example.

If you update the following line in your python `net-snmp` example,

```
res = netsnmp.snmpgetbulk(oid, Version=2, DestHost='192.168.0.100', 
                          Community='pub')
```

to

```
res = netsnmp.snmpwalk(oid, Version=2, DestHost='192.168.0.100', 
                       Community='pub')
```

then you should now get the same list of results from the python `net-snmp` example as you see when you do an `snmpwalk` on the command line.